# PDF linked to <object> not respecting CSS rules after the first Angular JS route change?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, object, pdf

I've created a little dummy "portfolio" for a job application demonstrating the use of Angular JS. One view on the site contains an object which contains a PDF version of my resume.

You can see this problem in action [here](http://allenhundley.com/#/resume).

Upon the first load of the view, the PDF fills the div as expected. After moving to a different view and returning, it defaults to a much smaller size.

Here is the HTML for this view...

```
<div id="format">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p id="text">
            Who hires someone without some background knowledge? You can read my resume here, or click the link below to download it in PDF format. 
        </p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <object id="resume-view" data="http://allenhundley.com/documents/resume.pdf" type='application/pdf'>
            <p>
                It looks like you don't have Adobe Reader installed! That's okay. Simply download my resume with the link below. 
            </p>
        </object>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://allenhundley.com/documents/resume.pdf" download="Resume - Allen Hundley.pdf">Download My Resume</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for this view (Loaded dynamically by Angular JS, everything else on this view gets the dynamic CSS applied quite nicely.):

```
#format {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    padding-top: 100px;

}

#header {

    float: left;
    width: 87px;
    height: 449px;
    background-image: url('http://allenhundley.com/images/resume/resume.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}

#text {

    display: inline;
    color: white; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;

}

#resume-view {

    height: 304px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid #99c2d1;

}
```

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing.

Why is the PDF not the appropriate size after a shift in route?